# High voltage wires

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, sound

We have bought a house near high tension wires (at a distance of around 20m). Will it be noisy during the rains, and more importantly will the ionization increase the risk of cancer?

Comment: This would have been good research **before** signing to buy.

Comment: The question might be recognized if you replace "tension"
 with "voltage".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they'll be noisy during rain, and even when it is misty or just humid out.  It'll make a humming crackling sound.

I'm not touching the question about ionization and cancer with a barge pole.  The available information comes from a spectrum of folks ranging from purveyors of tinfoil hats to power company owners, with steep and opposite slant on both sides.  This is an area where you're doomed to doing your own searches through the scientific literature *and* checking to see where the researchers get their funding.

Answer (score 0):

Biological systems respond to electricity in terms of *field strength* which gets measured in units of volts per meter. The field strength encountered when living under overhead power lines is about the same as the field strength encountered when sleeping in close contact with an electric blanket plugged into the AC mains.